# Using inner classes instead of global variables

Tags: python, class, nested, ros

I am trying to use a class to hold state instead of global variables. As an example, the object inner would like to reference the variable Outer.x (see example below)

I am doing this because I have a library that requires their own class input ([ros_smach](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach/Tutorials/Simple%20State%20Machine))

```
class Outer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 5

  class Inner:
    def __init__(self):
      self.y = 10

    def x(self):
      return Outer.x    ### this is not proper ###


outer = Outer()
inner = outer.Inner()
print outer.x
print inner.y
print inner.x()
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand (and therefore approve) of using an 'outer' class to hold state - you're substituting one form of global for another, and that is rarely a good idea. However, to answer your question, your inner class has no reference to the outer instance.

```
class Outer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 5
    self.inner = Inner(self)

  class Inner:
    def __init__(self, outer):
      self.outer = outer
      self.y = 10

    def x(self):
      return self.outer.x

o = Outer()
print o.x()
print o.inner.y
```